# Android protect manifest admob

Tags: java, android, admob, proguard

I try to protect my application, because someone can use reverse engineering. I use proguard, but it is still easy to remove ads from my application, by editing manifest.xml. Even I can remove ads from my .apk just deleting this line in my manifest.

```
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

Can I check my manifest in Java or there is other way to do that?

Comment: Reverse engineering will help the party change your `java code` as well.

Comment: I know, but it is much harder to edit java code, than xml code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this function to check if Admob Activity is still there. Please tell us if it works.

```
public boolean isAdmobThere(Context context) {
    return context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(new Intent(context, com.google.ads.AdActivity.class), 0).size() > 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't know why, but it return false all the time, even if it is there.

Comment: Sorry I edited the answer. You should replace `PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY` with `0`.

Comment: Mayby I do something wrong, but when I call it in my main UI class ("Menu") isAdmobThere(Menu.this) it return false

Comment: Oh my god. Sorry, use `queryIntentActivities` instead of `queryIntentServices`. I updated the answer again. Sorry